# VNC replacement

Tags: gratis, virtual-machine

I would like to install VNC viewer on my PC, but the website https://realvnc.com seems not to respond.

Is this a temporary problem (it occured yesterday too), do I need to get that installer somewhere else or is there another tool (preferably freeware) which replaces VNC viewer?

**Edit:** test, using FireFox browser:

Used URL: https://www.realvnc.com/en/connect/download/viewer/windows/

[image]

**Edit 2:**
I don't see that privacy notice anymore.
When I click on the `Not Secure` button, this is the screen I get:

[image]

Clicking on the `General` tab reveals the following:

[image]

Clicking on the `Permissions` tab shows the following:

[image]

What can I do?

Comment: When going to the link indicated the site appeared (I use Windows and Firefox)

Comment: @albert: thanks for the quick response, but even while using Firefox, it doesn't work.

Comment: I just tried the link you provided and this does work for me, maybe there is some information in the tab"Firefox Privacy Notice" that I see in your screen dump.

Comment: As I don't see the privacy notice anymore, I've decided to click on the `Not Secure` button instead. The results are in the next edit of my question.

Comment: I'm sorry but I have at the moment no ideas how this can happen. Maybe you are behind a firewall that is blocking?

Comment: In the meanwhile I managed to download it using my smartphone. Thanks for the help.